# Play Framework hide links when authenticated using template engine

Tags: java, templates, playframework

Im doing a website with the play framework and it's template engine. Everything works out fine except im unhappy with the fact that the register link is still visible when logged in.

```
   <div class="topbar">
    <div class="fill">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="@routes.Application.index()">L8</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="@routes.RegisterForm.register()">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="@routes.Terms.terms()">ToS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to hide the link from the nav bar when authenticated

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you want to implement all the authorization yourself. I'd recommend to user Deadbolt module for Play: https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2 . It has all the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The concrete solution of course depends on your specific authentication solution. But basically you can use some function from a helper class/object that tells you if the user is logged in or not, and depending on this information you can display the register link or not.

For a play demo I had done it like this, as you can see in [this template checking if the user is logged in](https://github.com/magro/play-product-finder/blob/master/app/views/tags/navOptionsMenu.scala.html#L8):

```
@ShopsController.loggedInUser.map { username =>
  Logged in user: @username
}.getOrElse {
  <a href="...">Login</a>
}
```

And the `ShopsController` (which could be any other helper object) respectively the [ShopsSecurity trait](https://github.com/magro/play-product-finder/blob/master/app/controllers/ShopsSecurity.scala) in my case (extended by `ShopsController`) [checks if the user is logged in and if so retrieves the username](https://github.com/magro/play-product-finder/blob/master/app/controllers/ShopsSecurity.scala#L86):

```
def loggedInUser(implicit request: Request[_]): Option[String] = request match {
  case authReq: Security.AuthenticatedRequest[_, _] => Some(authReq.user.asInstanceOf[String])
  case _ => None
}
```

This check obviously depends on the implementation being based on Play's built in `Security.AuthenticatedRequest`.

If you're looking for a sample using java you can check out my [play2-java-computer-database sample](https://github.com/magro/play2-java-computer-database) and specifically the [main template](https://github.com/magro/play2-java-computer-database/blob/master/play-coda/app/views/main.scala.html#L25) and the [Secured helper class](https://github.com/magro/play2-java-computer-database/blob/master/play-coda/app/utils/Secured.java).